# Is there any shortcut in C# when it comes to get; and set; which call onPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#

I have this code that I use to set properties in my application:

```
string _backgroundColor;
public string BackgroundColor
{
    get => _backgroundColor;
    set => SetProperty(ref _backgroundColor, value);
}
```

and

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(
            ref T backingStore, T value,
            [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
            Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
     }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

I remember reading something about where in C# I can use { get; set; }.  Is there any way that I could use that in this instance so I didn't have to keep declaring the local variables myself?

Comment: Nothing built in. You can certainly make some small method you can call for this but for it to correctly handle all types it quickly becomes a bit more complex than just simply adding the method call directly.

Comment: Simply: no. As soon as you implement any logic within your getter/setter, you will need the backing-field. By the way: the compiler creates that for you in case of an auto-implemented property (`get; set`)  for you anyway.

Comment: _Longs for the days of c/c++ and macros_

Comment: @MickyD *I thank the "gods" (Anders Hejlsberg, Mads Torgersen, et al) every day that they didn't add macros or templates to C#*

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen lol.  Live dangerously;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code already shows the typical shortcut for properties in classes implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. Using plain C# there is no shorter way. If you only use {get;set;} you lose the possibility to call anything inside the getter and setter.

If you simply want to automate the addition of PropertyChanged calls (and losing some control over it), you could look into Aspect Oriented Programming, for example using [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net) (commercial) or [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) (open source). These tools modify your code on / after compile time and allow for rules to modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

I see a suggestion to use PostSharp's [NotifyPropertyChanged] my responsibility is to mention a superior and free alternative:  Stepen Cleary's Calculated Properties.
https://github.com/StephenCleary/CalculatedProperties/blob/master/README.md

Clarification: Postsharp does allow you to write short form i.e.

```
string { get; set; }
```

and fire notification.
This is the only benefit over Calculated Properties, they're bit more verbose but still you don't need a backing field:

```
{
    get { return Property.Get(string.Empty); }
    set { Property.Set(value); }
}
```

You will quickly discover though that amount of typing is a minor concern, major challenge is properties that depend on other properties, and this is where CalculatedProperties beat PostSharp in all aspects.

From PostSharp docs:

"If a property getter calls a virtual method from its class or a delegate, or references a property of another object (without using canonical form this.field.Property), PostSharp will generate an error because it cannot resolve such a dependency at build time. The same limitations apply when your property getter contains complex data flows, such as loops, or calls to methods (except property getters) of other classes.
When this happens, you can either refactor your code so that it can be automatically analyzed by PostSharp, or you can take over the responsibility for analyzing the code"

None of those limitations apply to Calculated Properties. It can do loops, virtual methods, LINQ to objects, basically any crazy runtime dependencies that you can imagine doesn't matter how indirect, dependency graph rewires itself at runtime and just works without any ceremony. 
They are also faster and free.